# How to port forwarding/tunneling TCP on Nginx

Tags: nginx, tcp

I am using nginX
`nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)`

I have an app listening TCP on IPv4 port besides 80.
How I can to proxy/forward from domain on TCP 80 to this port.
What keywords should I find or nginx configurations?

Thanks

Comment: How did you solve this? Can you share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is reverse proxy

[Here is great tutorial how to forward connection from nginx to apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-16-04-server)

This tutorial shows how to forward connection from nginx on port 80 to apache on port 8080

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Question is what keywords he should look for and my answer was reverse proxy. Not sure what's wrong with it but i'll read thread you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: i am not using apache. I want to forwarding TCP connection from binding apps to another apps. It is not HTTP

Answer (score 0):

There are some options:

- You can use ssh-forwarding:

  ```
  plink <ssh user>@<server_ip> -pw <ssh pass> -L 0.0.0.0:<external port>:<target ip in internal network>:<target port in internal network>
  ```
- Create VPN by OpenVPN for example
- Check here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290223/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-different-port-numbers

Comment: unluckily it is not http proto